# javascript scope of function declarations

Tags: javascript, function, scope

The `var` keyword in javascript causes a variable to be stored in the local scope.  Without `var` variables belong to the global scope.  What about functions?  It's clear what happens when functions are declared like variables

```
var foo = function() {...}
```

but what scope does

```
function foo() {...}
```

belong to?

EDIT:
I realized I didn't ask quite the right question so as a follow up.  In the outer most nesting is there a difference between the above two declarations and the following declaration?

```
foo = function() {...}
```

Answer (score 28, accepted):

It belongs to the *current* scope, always. For example:

```
// global scope

// foo is a global function
function foo() {

    // bar is local to foo
    function bar() {

    }

}
```

Regarding your second question, this:

```
foo = function() {...}
```

is an anonymous function expression assigned to a global variable (unless you're running is strict mode, then `foo` would be undefined). The difference between that and `function foo() {}` is that the latter is a function *declaration* (versus a *variable* declaration, which is assigned an anonymous function *expression*).

You might be interested in this excellent article about function declarations and function expressions: [Named function expressions demystified](https://kangax.github.io/nfe/).

Comment: Thats a great article.  Thanks.

Comment: One notable difference I forgot to mention is what Bergi said in his answer: function declarations are hoisted, so you may call the function before it actually appears in the source code.

Answer (score 11):

Function declarations are always local to the current scope, like a variable declared with the `var` keyword.

However, the difference is that if they are *declared* (instead of assigned to a variable) their definition is *hoisted*, so they will be usable everywhere in the scope even if the declaration comes in the end of the code. See also [var functionName = function() {} vs function functionName() {}](https://stackoverflow.com/q/336859/1048572).

Answer (score 6):

Noteworthy distinction taking implicit globals into account:

```
var foo = function() {
  // Variables
  var myVar1 = 42;  // Local variable
      myVar2 = 69;  // Implicit global (no 'var')

  // Functional Expressions
  var myFn1 = function() { ... }  // Local 
      myFn2 = function() { ... }  // Implicit global

  function sayHi() {
    // I am a function declaration. Always local.
  }
}
```

Hopefully that clarifies a little. Implicit globals are defined if you forget a `var` before your assignment. Its a dangerous hazard that applies to variable declarations and functional expressions.

Answer (score 0):

Your first example (`var foo = function() {...}`) is called an anonymous function.  It is dynamically declared at runtime, and doesn't follow the same rules as a normal function, but follows the rules of variables.

Comment: which is really confusing because a lot of documentation says things like "functions are first class objects" without a more rigorous discussion about the distinction I mentioned in the OP.